# Changing the order of the entries of the bibtex-autokey generator-*

Tags: bibtex, org-ref

I am trying to migrate from Zotero to org-ref, and got stuck when trying to use the `doi-utils-add-bibtex-entry-from-doi` command. After reading the [Automatic Reference Key Generation](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/bibtex-mode.html#0630) section and searching online couldn't find an answer to this question. Can I change the order of the auto-generated entries (author, year, title), for example, to have an author_title_year bibtex key? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the components of the key are hard-coded, so you can't change them with a user option. However, you can re-write the function to set the order you want. You need to load your modified function *after* the original version, so your modification will replace it. The following code does this:

```elisp
(eval-after-load "bibtex"
  '(defun bibtex-generate-autokey ()
    (let* ((names (bibtex-autokey-get-names))
           (year (bibtex-autokey-get-year))
           (title (bibtex-autokey-get-title))
           (autokey (concat
                     bibtex-autokey-prefix-string ;; optional prefix string
                     names
                     (unless (or (equal names "")
                                 (equal title ""))
                       "_") ;; string to separate names from title
                     title
                     (unless (or (and (equal names "")
                                      (equal title ""))
                                 (equal year ""))
                       bibtex-autokey-year-title-separator)
                     year)))
      (if bibtex-autokey-before-presentation-function
          (funcall bibtex-autokey-before-presentation-function autokey)
        autokey))))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I am surprised that this option does not exist by default. Thanks!